# filtering file by using two conditions

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file

```
> head map.stats
ID=NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053289.1;Parent=NbD053289.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;matches=702;mismatches=0;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053288.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053288.1;Parent=NbD053288.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=99.8;matches=482;mismatches=1;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053287.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053287.1;Parent=NbD053287.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=94.1;matches=738;mismatches=0;indels=46;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053281.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053281.1;Parent=NbD053281.1.path1;coverage=99.3;identity=99.1;matches=1476;mismatches=14;indels=0;unknowns=0
```

and I would like filter out `$identity >= 95 && $coverage == 100` so I could get this output

```
ID=NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053289.1;Parent=NbD053289.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;matches=702;mismatches=0;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053288.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053288.1;Parent=NbD053288.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=99.8;matches=482;mismatches=1;indels=0;unknowns=0
```

I tried `grep -oP '(?<=identity=).*?(?=;)' map.stats | awk '$1 >= 99'` but it did not get me far. How is it possible to do this filtering?

Thank you in advane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first lets convert field to number using

```
awk -F= 'NR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%2d %s\n",i,$i ;}' file
 1 ID
 2 NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name
 3 NbD053289.1;Parent
 4 NbD053289.1.path1;coverage
 5 100.0;identity
 6 100.0;matches
 7 702;mismatches
 8 0;indels
 9 0;unknowns
10 0
```

so coverage is 5 and identity is 6

next, we can't directly use awk's `==` since it will match string, so we convert to number using +1.

this yield

```
awk -F= '$6+1>96 && ($5+1) == 101' file
ID=NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053289.1;Parent=NbD053289.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;matches=702;mismatches=0;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053288.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053288.1;Parent=NbD053288.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=99.8;matches=482;mismatches=1;indels=0;unknowns=0
```

where

- `-F=` tell awk to use `=` as separator
- `$6+1>96` convert to number as explained above and filter

Comment: The problem isn't that `==` does string matching, the string `100` is still the same as the string `100`. The problem is that you have a `;` at the end of the field and that breaks the match.

Comment: Is there a reason you're coercing a string to a num using `$6+1` rather than just `$6+0` ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma no, one could also use 42,which is kind of universal answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
$ awk -F'[;=]' '$10>=95 && $8 == 100' file
ID=NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053289.1;Parent=NbD053289.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;matches=702;mismatches=0;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053288.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053288.1;Parent=NbD053288.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=99.8;matches=482;mismatches=1;indels=0;unknowns=0
```

The trick is to set the field separator to either `;` or `=` (this is what `-F'[;=]'` does). Then, the value for `identity` will be the 10th field and the value for `coverage` will be the 8th. Since `awk`'s default action when an expression evaluates to true is to print the current line, this means that `$10>=95 && $8 == 100` will print any lines matching both those conditions.

---

You could, actually, do this with GNU `grep` as well, but you don't want the `-o` option since you want the whole line and there's no reason to use lookbehinds. All you need is to define the range. Since you want values from `95` to `100` (`>=95`), that means you want either a `9` followed by any one number between `5` and `9`, or a `100`:

```
$ grep  -P 'coverage=100.0.*identity=(9[5..9]|100)' file 
ID=NbD053289.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053289.1;Parent=NbD053289.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;matches=702;mismatches=0;indels=0;unknowns=0
ID=NbD053288.1.mrna1;Name=NbD053288.1;Parent=NbD053288.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=99.8;matches=482;mismatches=1;indels=0;unknowns=0
```

Note that I am assuming that identity cannot take values greater than 100, which seems like a safe assumption since you are presumably looking at sequence conservation and you can't get more similar than 100% identical.